# Securing RESTFul WebServices

Tags: tls, web-service, rest

I am planning to secure my REST Web service (REST WS) using API KEY and NONCE VALUE. The REST WS is over SSL.

The Userid / Password is encrypted and sent to Web Application hosting the REST WS where the Application decodes it and Authenticates it.

```
Would there be any mechanism by which it can get hold of the UID / PSWD 
from Mobile App calling this REST WS or via a Client Browser ?
```

In order to prevent this , lets say I apply NONCE , where the Client calls to get Nonce Value and then attaches this to UID and Password ?

```
How do I secure the NONCE API over the web where browser or mobile can call it ?
```

Comment: Use the OAuth 2.0 protocol instead to secure you API. the open standard of OAuth 2 provides a secure and open source method to authenticate and track applications making requests to your REST WS.